# Teradata SQL Find numbers in a Character field

Tags: sql, search, numbers, teradata

I have a table with a character column called "Name".  In some cases the "Name" columns contains string with just characters.  In other cases it contains any of the 10 numeric digits (i.e. 0 - 9).  I want to query this table and only produce the records where the Name column contains any numbers (0 -9) regardless of what order the numbers are in or in what position they are in.  Below is a hypothetical example:
The table contains the following 5 records of data in the Name column:
"ABC Company" ,
"Terry Smith" ,
"Trucking 365 LLC" ,
"Lumber3foryou" ,
"24/7 Carwash"

I want to create a query that will produce the Name column with only those records that have any number (0 - 9), regardless of what order the numbers are in or in what positions they are in.

So the output should include only the last three records:

"Trucking 365 LLC" ,
"Lumber3foryou" ,
"24/7 Carwash"

Answer (score 1):

You can use REGEXP_INSTR :

```
select
name
from
<table>
where
REGEXP_INSTR (name,'[0-9]') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be:

```
name like any ('%0%','%1%','%2%','%3%','%4%',
               '%5%','%6%','%7%','%8%','%9%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM <table>
WHERE name LIKE ANY ('%0%','%1%','%2%','%3%','%4%','%5%','%6%','%7%','%8%','%9%');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?